# Is this a question for Physics or Engineering community?

Tags: support

I have a question about forces required to lift weights, and I need someone to look over my math.  Should I ask this in Physics or Engineering community?

Answer (score 5):

If all you want is for someone to check your math, that is not on topic for this site. You could ask in [our chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71) though.

I can't speak for [Engineering SE](https://engineering.stackexchange.com), since that's a different site and I don't know their scope all that well. You would have to ask there.